# Diffeomorphism to $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$

Tags: manifolds, diffeomorphism

I'm into manifolds, and inside the proof of an example, the author says is is "clear to see" that $$(\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\})/G \text{ is diffeomorph to } \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^{n-1},$$ where $G = \{f^k | f^k(x)=2^kx, k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

It is clear to me that $G$ acts discontinously in $\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$, but I could not go further.

Could someone give me a hand in here?

Comment: Write $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$ as $\mathbb{R}_{+} \times S^{n-1}$ by sending a nonzero vector $v$ to the pair $(|v|, \frac{v}{|v|})$. What effect does this group action have in terms of this decomposition?

Comment: It also "seems" to be missing a coordinate, when I use your tip, since $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, so, I do not see how it helps.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Just think about how $f$ acts with respect to this decomposition and you'll get the answer.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan sorry, man. I can see how your decomposition "seem" to be helpfull, but I do not know how to work around the problem of having one coordinate missing.

Comment: There isn't any coordinate "missing." Try starting with the case $n = 1$ first. If you need an extra hint, take logarithms.

Comment: I still think there is a missing coordinate, buuut, I tried to work around with the following: $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}/G \rightarrow S^1 \times S^{n-1}$, by mapping $\bar{x} \mapsto (\|x\|,\|x\|,\frac{x}{\|x\|})$, which seems to be a difeomorphism. 

Does it make sense?

Comment: In what sense is $(\|x\|, \|x\|)$ a point on $S^1$ if $x$ is any non-zero element of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting my comments into an answer for clarity: we have a diffeomorphism

$$\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \} \ni v \mapsto \left( \| v \|, \frac{v}{\| v \|} \right) \in \mathbb{R}_{+} \times S^{n-1}$$

generalizing the polar decomposition for $n = 2$. The multiplication-by-$2$ map acts only on the first factor $\mathbb{R}_{+}$, and the quotient is diffeomorphic to $S^1$ via the map

$$\mathbb{R}_{+} \ni r \mapsto \exp \left( 2 \pi i \log_2 r \right) \in S^1.$$

There is no issue with "missing coordinates." The point is that after taking $\log_2$, the multiplication-by-$2$ map on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ corresponds to the addition-by-$1$ map on $\mathbb{R}$, which gives a circle $S^1 \cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ as usual.